# How to use factory method with multi string parameters to create a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, factory

I have a factory function with two string parameters (each parameter indicates a class). How could I reduce using `if` branches?

```cpp
A create_A(string type, string order){
    if (type=="LLT" && order == "AMD"){
        return A<LLT, AMD>();
    }
    elif(type=="LLT" && order=="COLAMD"){
        return A<LLT, COLAMD>();
    }
    elif(type=="LU" && order=="AMD"){
        return A<LU, AMD>();
    }
    elif(type=="LU", && order="COLAMD"){
        return A<LU, COLAMD>();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have tried this, too. But I would still like to reduce the `if` branches.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Base> create_A(string type, string order){
    if (type=="LLT" && order == "AMD"){
        return std::make_unique<Derived<LLT, AMD>>();
    }
    else if(type=="LLT" && order=="COLAMD"){
        return std::make_unique<Derived<LLT, COLAMD>>();
    }
    else if(type=="LU" && order=="AMD"){
        return std::make_unique<Derived<LU, AMD>>();
    }
    else if(type=="LU", && order="COLAMD"){
        return std::make_unique<Derived<LU, COLAMD>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: "elif" is not a thing in C++. And you can't return different types from the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reduce this code would be to use a `std::(unsorted_)map` with a `std::pair<std::string,std::string>` as the key type, and lambdas or free functions as the value type.

However, a function can't return different types, and `A<w,x>` is a distinct type from `A<y,z>`. If you really want this to work, you  should derive `A` from a non-template base class, return a pointer to that base class, and then create your `A` objects dynamically, eg:

```cpp
using key_type = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using func_type = std::unique_ptr<Base> (*)();

#define MAKE_ENTRY(type, order) {{#type, #order}, []() -> std::unique_ptr<Base> { return std::make_unique<Derived<type, order>>(); }

std::unique_ptr<Base> create_A(string type, string order){
    static std::unordered_map<key_type, func_type> A_types = {
        MAKE_ENTRY(LLT, AMD),
        MAKE_ENTRY(LLT, COLAMD),
        MAKE_ENTRY(LU,AMD),
        MAKE_ENTRY(LU, COLAMD)
    }:

    auto func = A_types.at(std::make_pair(type, order));
    return func();
}
```

Comment: Or return some form of *pointer to* Base instead of the object by value.  That would work.

Comment: @Joe I literally said that in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I re-edit the post according to your answer.
`lambdas or free functions as the value type.` is exactly what I want to do. But I don't know if it could work when `LLT` and `Order` are classes in my example.

Comment: Sorry.  Brain fart.  I was reading your comment to his question but replying to your answer